# Find Groups Whose Direct Products are Isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Give an example of groups $H_i$ and $K_i$ such that $H_1 \times H_2 \simeq K_1 \times K_2$ and no $H_i$ is isomorphic to any $K_i$.

Would this work? Let $H_1 = V_4$, the Klein 4-group, $H_2 = \{e\}$, and $K_1 = K_2 = Z_2$. Then $Z_2 \times Z_2 \simeq V_4 \simeq V_4 \times \{e\}$, and clearly neither $V_4 \simeq Z_2$ nor $\{e\} \simeq Z_2$.

Comment: Why look for something so complicated ? Take $K_1, K_2$ non trivial groups, $H_1$ the trivial group and $H_2 = K_1\times K_2$

Comment: @Max Isn't that exactly what he did?

Comment: @DerekHolt So, does my example work?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't read right, I was sure he/she had done something more complicated. Your example works fine